# How do you refer to parent Application in a class that isn't a UIComponent?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flash-builder

When an http error is received by the controller in my Flex app, I need to display an error and then return the user to the login page. If I'm catching that error in a UIComponent, I can use:

```
 this.parentApplication.currentState = "login";
```

But how do I do this from a class that isn't a UIComponent?

Thanks.

EDIT: I know I can dispatch a custom event and listen for it elsewhere in the app; I'm just wondering if there's a more direct way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the application object as `mx.core.FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication` from anywhere in the application.

See the docs [about the application object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e3a.html)